# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS) during execution of malloc()

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, osx-leopard, memory-access

I am compiling a C library in Mac OS X Snow Leopard with the folloing GCC:

```
Diderot:~ brandizzi$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin10
Configured with: /var/tmp/gcc/gcc-5666.3~6/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/usr --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin10 --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin10- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin10 --target=i686-apple-darwin10 --with-gxx-include-dir=/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)
```

When I run some unit tests of this library (which are written on [CuTest](http://cutest.sourceforge.net/)) one of the tests got a problem: an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal. That is a usual problem and I have some understanding about this kind of issue - I'm a Linux guy who called it "Segmentation fault", understand what is happening and the usual ways to solve the problem. What is amazing is that the bad access is executed *inside the execution of `malloc` function*. Look at this backtrace I've got in GDB:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fff89000a34 in tiny_free_list_add_ptr ()
#1  0x00007fff88ffe147 in tiny_malloc_from_free_list ()
#2  0x00007fff88ffcfdd in szone_malloc_should_clear ()
#3  0x00007fff88ffceaa in malloc_zone_malloc ()
#4  0x00007fff88ffb1a8 in malloc ()
#5  0x0000000100008c72 in util_copy_string (string=0x100008e48 "libsecretary") at src/util.c:7
#6  0x0000000100008126 in project_new (name=0x100008e48 "libsecretary") at src/project.c:8
#7  0x00000001000078b9 in secretary_start (secretary=0x10080b000, name=0x100008e48 "libsecretary") at src/secretary.c:23
#8  0x00000001000020f8 in test_secretary_move_task_from_project_to_project (test=0x1001005b0) at src/test/secretary.c:146
#9  0x0000000100006eae in CuTestRun (tc=0x1001005b0) at cutest/CuTest.c:143
#10 0x00000001000075c1 in CuSuiteRun (testSuite=0x100800000) at cutest/CuTest.c:289
#11 0x0000000100001527 in RunAllTests () at src/test/run_all.c:22
#12 0x000000010000156b in main () at src/test/run_all.c:32
```

This test case has the following lines, and the error always happens at the fourth one. If I switch the lines in any way, the problem still happens at the fourth one:

```
Secretary *secretary = secretary_new();
Task *task = secretary_appoint(secretary, "Test task transference");
Project *destination = secretary_start(secretary, "Chocrotary");
Project *origin = secretary_start(secretary, "libsecretary");
```

So, how can `malloc()` cause such problem? I do not even pass a pointer to it! Is it a bug? Has someone seen something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, something earlier in the program's execution is writing to memory it isn't entitled to, corrupting the heap's data structures. Then, later, `malloc` gets called and tries to follow a pointer that's been overwritten with nonsense (or index something via a value that's being overwritten with nonsense, or whatever), and boom.

You might want to try running your test suite under `valgrind` to see where things first start going wrong.

Comment: I effectively used valgrind and did not find the source of the problem... Actually, I did not understand very well how to read its output - it pointed problems but I did not understand what it meant. However, I've made some code review and rewriting and solved the problem. I do not know exactly where the problem relied but it is solved. Since valgrind seems to be a great tool, however, I'll mark ths answer as accepted, also because the problem seems to be corrupted heap anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an awful lot of reasons for this problem: one did not allocate the memory, the pointer points to the wrong place etc. etc.

In my case, I was allocating an array of e.g. `Project` with `MAX_PROJECT_COUNT` positions. I wrote

```
Project *array = malloc(MAX_PROJECT_COUNT);
```

but it does not consider the size of the `Project` struct! The correct solution would be

```
Project *array = malloc(MAX_PROJECT_COUNT*sizeof(Project));
```

Note, however, that your problem may be considerably different so it is not possible to apply the same solution.